# Scrapy - Problems scraping simple website

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to setup a simple spider to regularly check [a webpage](http://journals.ametsoc.org/toc/wefo/current/) to pull simple data on published articles (title and abstract url).

I've setup the spider as follows:

```
class JournalSpider(Spider):
    name = "journal"
    allowed_domains = ["ametsoc.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://journals.ametsoc.org/toc/wefo/current/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        journalTitle = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="journalBlurbPanel"]/div[2]/h3/text()').extract()[0]
        journalIssue = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="articleToolsHeading"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()  # remove whitespace at start and end

        # find all articles for the issue and parse each one individually
        articles = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@id="rightColumn"]//table[@class="articleEntry"]')

        for article in articles:
            item = ArticleItem()
            item['journalTitle'] = journalTitle
            item['journalIssue'] = journalIssue
            item['title'] = article.xpath('//div[@class="art_title"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['url'] = article.xpath('//a/@href').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

This successfully pulls the `journalTitle` and `journalIssue` and even iterates 25 times, which is the number of articles on the page, however each article has the same `title` (the title of the first article). Furthermore, I do not know where the `url` is being pulled from as it doesn't correlate to anything that I can see on the page: `/action/ssostart?idp=https%3A%2F%2Fshib.ametsoc.org%2Fshibboleth%2Fidp`

I feel like I must either be messing up my xpath string (I'm new to fiddling around with xpaths, so I wouldn't be surprised if that's the case!), or perhaps I'm being served a different version of the site when accessed via Scrapy?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XPath expressions in the loop have to be *context-specific and start with a dot*:

```
item['title'] = article.xpath('.//div[@class="art_title"]/text()').extract()[0]
item['url'] = article.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()[0]
```

You can also use the `extract_first()` method instead of `extract()[0]` and use `response.xpath()` shortcut instead of `Selector(response).xpath()`.

Comment: Such a simple solution, as they often are. Thanks for the bonus syntax tips too.

Comment: Hey @alecxe what does `.` signify in xpath?

Comment: @NikhilParmar it basically means - start traversing and searching from the current node and not from the document root.